# Display graphics in plots window pane rather than opening new window in RStudio

Tags: r, plot, graphics, rstudio

I googled this to no avail. I must have unknowingly changed some setting because now when I print a plot or histogram rather than displaying the plot in the plots window, a new window opens with the plot. The title of the new window reads "R Graphics: Device 2 (ACTIVE)".

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution to this?

Comment: Any solution for the same?

Answer (score 5):

It is a problem that appeared with R 3.3.0 for some RStudio versions. You can check your version with `version` in RStudio.
It should work with a RSudio 0.99.902.

For more details, check [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/209547948-No-graphs-in-the-plot-pane).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13237071)

Comment: I have edited the post to avoid the link-only answer effect.

Comment: I've updated Rstudio from 0.99.457 to the newest version 0.99.903 and it fixed the issue, created by update to R 3.3.1

Answer (score 1):

Some code you ran probably pushed a new graphics device onto the stack. You can turn it off with:

```
> dev.off()
```

See the [R documentation for managing output devices](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/dev.html).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Jonathan. I tried dev,off() and get the error message "Error in dev.off() : cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)".

Comment: And I get the following when I run the code from the link provided: > dev.off()
Error in dev.off() : cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)
> dev.cur()
null device 
          1 
> dev.list()
NULL
> dev.next(which = dev.cur())
null device 
          1 
> dev.prev(which = dev.cur())
null device 
          1 
> dev.off(which = dev.cur())
Error in dev.off(which = dev.cur()) : 
  cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)
> dev.set(which = dev.next())
null device 
          1 
> dev.new(..., noRStudioGD = FALSE)
Error: '...' used in an incorrect context
> graphics.off()

Comment: For default device 1 cannot be closed. But if you have several devices open (e.g multiple graphics) you can choose with dev.off() which device will be closed.