# How to turn off RStudio popping new window when I plot any graph?

Tags: r, rstudio

Earlier I was getting plot result in RStudio window itself. Then I guess I did something now every time I plot something it creates it in a new window. How to toggle this feature? I tried even restarting RStudio but this issue has persisted. I guess it has something to do with dev.off() or dev.new() , I tried playing with these options but it didn't help

Comment: I found this which is related.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40681696/how-to-plot-in-rstudio-and-not-have-a-new-window-pop-up-r-graphics-device-act

Comment: yea but there too no solution is posted.

Answer (score 0):

I closed all my open windows and ran dev.off() until "null device" printed.