# ggplot error in if (node$tag == "span") after trying to split a faceted plot over multiple pages

Tags: r, ggplot2

My dataset includes the variable "annual_TRW" measured over different "survey_year", with 5 "Sample_Core_ID" within each "block" nested within each "site".
The following code was working to plot all samples for a plot subset.

```
pdf("plots.pdf")
library(ggplot2)

dataset %>%
  group_by(site, block, Sample_Core_ID ) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = survey_year, y = annual_TRW, colour = Sample_Core_ID)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(Sample_Core_ID ~ .)

dev.off()
```

Then, I was trying to split a faceted plot over multiple pages, with each page including the faceted plots (1 column, 5 rows) corresponding to the samples of each block. I was testing using different different functions `ggplus::facet_multiple`, `gridExtra::marrangeGrob`, and `ggforce::facet_wrap_paginate`, but without success i.e. pdf were created empty.

The problem is that, after trying different options, now I get the following error every time that I try to use any ggplot on the same dataset. Now, I dont manage to plot the code that worked before without giving this error.

```
Error in if (node$tag == "span") { : argument is of length zero
```

Question 1: How can I solve this error every time I try to use this ggplot?
Question 2: Once this works again, how can I split the faceted plot over multiple pages as explained before?

Thanks a lot in advance!

I tried re-running the entire code, and re-calling the packages, but it doesnt work.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data so that we can run your code, reproduce your issue and try to figure out a solution.

Comment: Two things: (1) group back-to-back `group_by`s in general makes little sense, though it _might_ make sense if you included `.add=TRUE`. (2) Your pipe ends after the first `group_by(.)`, so your second `group_by` is starting anew, assuming that `site` is a frame (which, by your first group, it would seem that `site` is a column within `dataset`, not a frame on its own). At a minimum (ignoring the meaningless double-group-by), add a `%>%` after your first `group_by(..)`.

Comment: Also ... `ggplot2` doesn't care about dplyr groups, so `group_by(..) %>% ggplot(..)` does nothing. For this, you might as well use `dataset %>% filter(plot == 1) %>% ggplot(...) + ...`

Comment: @Stefan: Thanks for the suggested link about how to create a minimal reproducible example, I was not awared of the ```dput()``` function to extract part of my dataset as an example

Comment: Regarding Problem 1: the error was solved after updating the R version and reinstalling only the necessary packages that worked. The issue might have come from installing the packages ```ggplus``` as described here https://github.com/guiastrennec/ggplus

Comment: @r2evans: thanks for spotting the mistake with the double ```group_by```, a mistake when writing the post, now corrected as it was in the original code.  
I also updated to remove the first filter, which was just an example to check for a single ggplot that was related to my Question/Problem 1. 

The question 2 is still open, how to split the faceted plot over multiple pages with each page showing the 5 ```Sample_Core_ID``` within each ```block```.

Comment: For question 2, the ggplus repo you linked to provides a reference to `ggforce::facet_*_paginate()`, have you tried either of them yet?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Problem 1: the error was "temporarily" solved after updating the R version and reinstalling only the necessary packages that worked. (I thought the issue might have come from installing the packages `ggplus` as described here https://github.com/guiastrennec/ggplus).

However, after updating the R version, a new issue appeared: [How to plot in RStudio and not have a new window pop up (R Graphics: Device (ACTIVE)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40681696/how-to-plot-in-rstudio-and-not-have-a-new-window-pop-up-r-graphics-device-act)

Then I solved it by updating the R studio version ..... BUT this returned me to the original problem again when trying to plot !!! =S =( So frustrating ...

`Error in if (node$tag == "span") { : argument is of length zero`