# RStudio opens plot in extra window instead of plot pane

Tags: rstudio

My RStudio opens plots in extra windows instead of the plot pane. How do I get RStudio to plot in the plot pane again? Restarting did not help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37264114/4533188 did not help either. My RStudio-Version is 1.0.136.

Answer (score 0):

I am a system administrator who just dealt with this same annoying problem on several workstations. This is actually a bug with RStudio that can be fixed by insuring that you are using the latest version of both R and Rstudio, and then *additionally* checking that RStudio is *actually using* the latest version of R.

My solution was to completely uninstall both R and RStudio, then reinstall both.

Comment: Seriously? But I did not have the problem two weeks ago and as far as I know I did not update (I think)...

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't a lot of information out there about this problem.

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/209547948-No-graphs-in-the-plot-pane

Comment: Should I update to RStudio version 1.0.143? And which R version?

Comment: I can't really tell you :( sorry. We use a special version of Rstudio that ties into our institutional cluster.